# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 3 column 1 path $

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2, jsonresponse

I am using retrofit2 with Gson Converter.

my server response is :

```
     {
    "resonse": {
        "status": 200,
        "result": [
            {
                "video_id": "3c19979979",
                "video_title": "Sushil Kumar Modi press conference after serial bomb blasts at Modi rally in Patna",
                "video_description": "BJP at Patna serial blast in Bihar, Nitish government has stood in the dock. Former Deputy Chief Minister Sushil Kumar Modi said the blasts Narendra Modi were targeted. He said that Nitish Kumar look Modi as the enemy.<br />\r\n",
                "video_poster": "https://vbcdn.com/cdn/download/2013102913830306761810268995.jpg",
                "video_duration": "02:02",
                "video_category": "News/Politics"
    }
  ]}
}
```

ANd this is my pojo class:

```
public class ResponseVideoList implements  Serializable {

    @SerializedName("resonse")
    @Expose
    private Resonse resonse;
    private final static long serialVersionUID = -2645239251698186770L;

    public Resonse getResonse() {
        return resonse;
    }

    public void setResonse(Resonse resonse) {
        this.resonse = resonse;
    }

    public class Resonse implements Serializable {

        @SerializedName("status")
        @Expose
        private Integer status;
        @SerializedName("result")
        @Expose
        private List<VIdeoItem> result = null;
        private final static long serialVersionUID = 3604737417113897610L;

        public Integer getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(Integer status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public List<VIdeoItem> getResult() {
            return result;
        }

        public void setResult(List<VIdeoItem> result) {
            this.result = result;
        }
    }

}
```

VideoItem class:

```
 public class VIdeoItem implements Serializable
{

@SerializedName("video_id")
@Expose
private String videoId;
@SerializedName("video_title")
@Expose
private String videoTitle;
@SerializedName("video_description")
@Expose
private String videoDescription;
@SerializedName("video_poster")
@Expose
private String videoPoster;
@SerializedName("video_duration")
@Expose
private String videoDuration;
@SerializedName("video_category")
@Expose
private String videoCategory;
private final static long serialVersionUID = -7124444558733051869L;

public String getVideoId() {
return videoId;
}

public void setVideoId(String videoId) {
this.videoId = videoId;
}

public String getVideoTitle() {
return videoTitle;
}

public void setVideoTitle(String videoTitle) {
this.videoTitle = videoTitle;
}

public String getVideoDescription() {
return videoDescription;
}

public void setVideoDescription(String videoDescription) {
this.videoDescription = videoDescription;
}

public String getVideoPoster() {
return videoPoster;
}

public void setVideoPoster(String videoPoster) {
this.videoPoster = videoPoster;
}

public String getVideoDuration() {
return videoDuration;
}

public void setVideoDuration(String videoDuration) {
this.videoDuration = videoDuration;
}

public String getVideoCategory() {
return videoCategory;
}

public void setVideoCategory(String videoCategory) {
this.videoCategory = videoCategory;
}

}
```

the response is not fetched properly I think and I have also tried other answers like this but did not get any proper solution for this particular problem.
 the line 3 is   "status": 200, this one but can't figure out the solution to this.

Retrofit client :

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request newRequest  = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                        .build();
                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        }).build();
       if (retrofit==null)
       retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               .client(client)
               .build();
        return retrofit;
```

API CLIENT :

```
  @Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
    @POST("video/list-video.php")
    Call<ResponseVideoList> getVideoListFromSearchText(@Body JsonObject jsonObject);
```

log:

2019-08-14 10:21:19.274 6777-8289/com.veblr.android.veblrapp    D/OkHttp: --> POST    https://api.com/api/veblr-app/veblrAppNews/video/list-video.php    2019-08-14 
10:21:19.274 6777-8289/com.veblr.android.veblrapp    D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json 
2019-08-14 10:21:19.275    6777-8289/com.veblr.android.veblrapp D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 45    2019-08-14 10:21:19.276 6777-8289/com.veblr.android.veblrapp    D/OkHttp: {"param":{"max_results":"1","search":"modi"}} 2019-08-14
10:21:19.276 6777-8289/com.veblr.android.veblrapp D/OkHttp: --> END    POST (45-byte body) 
2019-08-14 10:21:20.452    6777-8264/com.veblr.android.veblrapp V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting    from the service 
2019-08-14 10:21:20.466    6777-8289/com.veblr.android.veblrapp D/OkHttp: <-- 200    https://api.com/api/veblr-app/veblrAppNews/video/list-video.php    (1189ms) 
2019-08-14 10:21:20.466 6777-8289/com.veblr.android.veblrapp    D/OkHttp: server: nginx 2019-08-14 10:21:20.466    6777-8289/com.veblr.android.veblrapp D/OkHttp: date: Wed, 14 Aug 2019
04:51:23 GMT 2019-08-14 10:21:20.466    6777-8289/com.veblr.android.veblrapp D/OkHttp: content-type:    application/json 2019-08-14 10:21:20.466    6777-8289/com.veblr.android.veblrapp D/OkHttp: vary: Accept-Encoding
2019-08-14 10:21:20.467 6777-8289/com.veblr.android.veblrapp    D/OkHttp: access-control-allow-origin: * 2019-08-14 10:21:20.467    6777-8289/com.veblr.android.veblrapp D/OkHttp:    strict-transport-security: max-age=15768000 2019-08-14 10:21:20.472    6777-8289/com.veblr.android.veblrapp D/OkHttp: 
 2019-08-14
10:21:20.472 6777-8289/com.veblr.android.veblrapp D/OkHttp:    **Warning**:  Redis::connect(): connect() failed: Connection    refused in    **/home/veblr/public_html/api/veblr-app/veblrAppNews/config/redis.php**    on line **7**
 2019-08-14 10:21:20.472    6777-8289/com.veblr.android.veblrapp D/OkHttp:    { {"resonse":{"status":200,"result":[{"video_id":"3c19979979","video_title":"Sushil Kumar Modi press conference after serial bomb blasts at Modi rally in Patna","video_description":"BJP at Patna serial blast in Bihar, Nitish government has stood in the dock. Former Deputy Chief Minister Sushil Kumar Modi said the blasts Narendra Modi were targeted. He said that Nitish Kumar look Modi as the enemy.\r\n","video_poster":"https://vb.com/cdn/download/2013102913830306761810268995.jpg","video_duration":"02:02","video_category":"News/Politics"}]}} 
2019-08-14 10:21:20.473    6777-8289/com.veblr.android.veblrapp D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP    (1461-byte body) 2019-08-14 10:21:20.480    6777-6777/com.veblr.android.veblrapp E/FAiled:    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING    at line 3 column 1 path $

Comment: make sure your response is correct when you call it from app

Comment: @Radesh what do you mean by current?

Comment: Where is _VIdeoItem_ class where you should serialize all items of it

Comment: sorry, i mean some times response is wrong when you call it from app for example return simple string as resonse that tell error message and this couse problem

Comment: post your videoitem class

Comment: if the response is not according to this model, obviously retrofit will thow the exception. It has to be the above specified format or gson wont be able to parse it

Comment: the backend needs to ensure that this specific json format is followed in all cases

Comment: @Kushan so is there anything wrong with the model class for this response

Comment: @Piyush edited the question

Comment: PLease check your backend code for any `echo` or `print()`.

Comment: @DHAVALASODARIYA how to check that?

Comment: Ask the one who have developed services for frontEnd.

Comment: model is fine.... the backend has to stick to the standard response format in all cases. The app is not the problem

Comment: @Kushan it it giving the above server response in postman.

Comment: Also a tip: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/     use this for modeling the json to pojo classes. It saves a bunch of time and literally all u need to do is paste the json format and voila!

Comment: @Kushan yes i have generated the pojo classes from here only

Comment: can you add the retrofit call and the service in the question, i feel it's the call<?> which might be an issue then... By service i mean the Interface

Comment: Read carefully.. Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING. Its happening in your response.

Comment: Your model expect JSONOBject, but in response its coming as string... Locate the Json param and compare with response you received, which its expectation is not met.

Comment: @RajeshVijayakumar here it is state that the string is found at line 3 column 1 .so can you help me to find the exact line?

Comment: Please post the complete log here, then only will be able to locate your issue..

Comment: @RajeshVijayakumar edited my answer with log .

Comment: Can you add some more logs after java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 3 column 1 path $

Comment: @RajeshVijayakumar the http call is getting disconnected after this , so no more log after it.

Comment: Its not about HTTP call, its about post HTTP call where response is handled.. Please try to add logs at proper place and share the logs...

Comment: @RajeshVijayakumar yeah solved it by reviewing the log data.The problem was at the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Remove every thing in ResponseVideoList class and just Put this;
after that use this one class in your retrofit complete response will parse in this class

```
public class ResponseVideoList  {


    /**
     * resonse : {"status":200,"result":[{"video_id":"3c19979979","video_title":"Sushil Kumar Modi press conference after serial bomb blasts at Modi rally in Patna","video_description":"BJP at Patna serial blast in Bihar, Nitish government has stood in the dock. Former Deputy Chief Minister Sushil Kumar Modi said the blasts Narendra Modi were targeted. He said that Nitish Kumar look Modi as the enemy.<br />\r\n","video_poster":"https://vbcdn.com/cdn/download/2013102913830306761810268995.jpg","video_duration":"02:02","video_category":"News/Politics"}]}
     */

    private ResonseBean resonse;

    public ResonseBean getResonse() {
        return resonse;
    }

    public void setResonse(ResonseBean resonse) {
        this.resonse = resonse;
    }

    public static class ResonseBean {
        /**
         * status : 200
         * result : [{"video_id":"3c19979979","video_title":"Sushil Kumar Modi press conference after serial bomb blasts at Modi rally in Patna","video_description":"BJP at Patna serial blast in Bihar, Nitish government has stood in the dock. Former Deputy Chief Minister Sushil Kumar Modi said the blasts Narendra Modi were targeted. He said that Nitish Kumar look Modi as the enemy.<br />\r\n","video_poster":"https://vbcdn.com/cdn/download/2013102913830306761810268995.jpg","video_duration":"02:02","video_category":"News/Politics"}]
         */

        private int status;
        private List<ResultBean> result;

        public int getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(int status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public List<ResultBean> getResult() {
            return result;
        }

        public void setResult(List<ResultBean> result) {
            this.result = result;
        }

        public static class ResultBean {
            /**
             * video_id : 3c19979979
             * video_title : Sushil Kumar Modi press conference after serial bomb blasts at Modi rally in Patna
             * video_description : BJP at Patna serial blast in Bihar, Nitish government has stood in the dock. Former Deputy Chief Minister Sushil Kumar Modi said the blasts Narendra Modi were targeted. He said that Nitish Kumar look Modi as the enemy.<br />
             * video_poster : https://vbcdn.com/cdn/download/2013102913830306761810268995.jpg
             * video_duration : 02:02
             * video_category : News/Politics
             */

            private String video_id;
            private String video_title;
            private String video_description;
            private String video_poster;
            private String video_duration;
            private String video_category;

            public String getVideo_id() {
                return video_id;
            }

            public void setVideo_id(String video_id) {
                this.video_id = video_id;
            }

            public String getVideo_title() {
                return video_title;
            }

            public void setVideo_title(String video_title) {
                this.video_title = video_title;
            }

            public String getVideo_description() {
                return video_description;
            }

            public void setVideo_description(String video_description) {
                this.video_description = video_description;
            }

            public String getVideo_poster() {
                return video_poster;
            }

            public void setVideo_poster(String video_poster) {
                this.video_poster = video_poster;
            }

            public String getVideo_duration() {
                return video_duration;
            }

            public void setVideo_duration(String video_duration) {
                this.video_duration = video_duration;
            }

            public String getVideo_category() {
                return video_category;
            }

            public void setVideo_category(String video_category) {
                this.video_category = video_category;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After response you can access response.body().data something like that
Also you don't need to generate extra class

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Example implements Serializable
{

@SerializedName("resonse")
@Expose
private Resonse resonse;
private final static long serialVersionUID = 1058617649272447322L;

public Resonse getResonse() {
return resonse;
}

public void setResonse(Resonse resonse) {
this.resonse = resonse;
}

}



public class Resonse implements Serializable
{

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Integer status;
@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private List<Result> result = null;
private final static long serialVersionUID = 3708794248294394638L;

public Integer getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(Integer status) {
this.status = status;
}

public List<Result> getResult() {
return result;
}

public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
this.result = result;
}

}




public class Result implements Serializable
{

@SerializedName("video_id")
@Expose
private String videoId;
@SerializedName("video_title")
@Expose
private String videoTitle;
@SerializedName("video_description")
@Expose
private String videoDescription;
@SerializedName("video_poster")
@Expose
private String videoPoster;
@SerializedName("video_duration")
@Expose
private String videoDuration;
@SerializedName("video_category")
@Expose
private String videoCategory;
private final static long serialVersionUID = -7678430047668505370L;

public String getVideoId() {
return videoId;
}

public void setVideoId(String videoId) {
this.videoId = videoId;
}

public String getVideoTitle() {
return videoTitle;
}

public void setVideoTitle(String videoTitle) {
this.videoTitle = videoTitle;
}

public String getVideoDescription() {
return videoDescription;
}

public void setVideoDescription(String videoDescription) {
this.videoDescription = videoDescription;
}

public String getVideoPoster() {
return videoPoster;
}

public void setVideoPoster(String videoPoster) {
this.videoPoster = videoPoster;
}

public String getVideoDuration() {
return videoDuration;
}

public void setVideoDuration(String videoDuration) {
this.videoDuration = videoDuration;
}

public String getVideoCategory() {
return videoCategory;
}

public void setVideoCategory(String videoCategory) {
this.videoCategory = videoCategory;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

for helping you and find your issue use this library and see network logs and your response, then you can find your problem,

Add this to `dependencies`

```
 implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.0'
```

Now add it to your `OkHttpClient`

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
       .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
       .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request newRequest  = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }
    }).build();
```

Now after call api you can see logs in logcat and finding your problem

Comment: got the same response as postman but can't figure out  which one is line 3 column 1.

Comment: @Sushrita did you change JsonObject  to ResponseVideoList ?

Comment: why should I do that?

Comment: check my edited answer. i put correct API CLIENT for you. use that and tell me our problem solved or not

Comment: I am just asking you the necessity of doing it and it won't work i think

Comment: you must doing it because your response is ResponseVideoList not JsonObject

Comment: which i did it at     Call<ResponseVideoList> and JsonObject  is the data which I am sending