# how to get a object response while it gives array response

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, httpresponse

I want to register my user to the backend server of our company.

For that I create a Post request having @Header with api key and @Body with user info. But when I hit the api, in response it shows a response like this "data":[] where it should be like "data":{}

SignInInfo.kt

```
data class SignInInfo(
    @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
    @SerializedName("email") val email: String,
    @SerializedName("user_type") val userType: String,
    @SerializedName("phone") val phone: String,
    @SerializedName("password") val password: String
)
```

RegistrationResponse.kt

```
data class RegistrationResponse(
    @field:SerializedName("msg") val msg: String? = null,
    @field:SerializedName("data") val data: Data? = null,
    @field:SerializedName("status") val status: Int? = null
)
```

Data.kt

```
data class Data(
    @field:SerializedName("user_id") val userId: Int,
    @field:SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
    @field:SerializedName("token") val token: String
)
```

api.kt

```
@POST(Constants.API_USER_REGISTRATION)
fun registerUser(
    @Body signInInfo: SignInInfo
): Call<RegistrationResponse>
```

RetrofitBuilder.kt

```
object RetrofitBuilder {

    fun retrofit(baseUrl: String): Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(getOkHttpClient())
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    private fun getOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(headersInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build()
    }

}
```

ApiUtils.kt

```
object ApiUtils {

    val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
        level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    }

    val headersInterceptor = Interceptor {
        val request = it.request()

        it.proceed(
            request.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("api_key", "sr8fyw8hcow8efhisncsef0wefw9ef0swdcsopd")
                .build()
        )
    }
}
```

viewModel.kt

```
fun register(signInInfo: SignInInfo) {
        ApiFactory.userRegistrationApi.registerUser(signInInfo).enqueue(object :
            Callback<RegistrationResponse> {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<RegistrationResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("Got Error Here", t.toString())
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<RegistrationResponse>,
                response: Response<RegistrationResponse>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d("Success", response.body()?.msg)
                } else {
                    Log.d("error", response.message())
                }
            }

        })
    }
```

I expect output like this

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "data": {
        "id": 135386,
        "user_id": 1567057386,
        "token": "geYs2rO6wjtO653I9OVhJWTFwYxAvnYnLGG7wm7dfa"
    },
    "msg": "Welcome Aomi"
}
```

Comment: can you share your api?

Comment: @Radesh here it is https://base_url/api/register

Comment: what is base url? fill it

Comment: or you can test your api with post map and send response as picture here

Comment: It seems, you misunderstood how the API works.

Comment: without more information of how your API works it is impossible to give a decent response. Your response classes are organized correctly and it is impossible to receive an array instead of object with your current classes.

Comment: base url : https://caretutors.com/api/register @Radesh. And Sorry for late reply

Comment: here is the response image https://imgur.com/a/i7sz41i @Radesh

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for your response. But I did not understand what the actual problem was. however what type of info do you need brother. I can provide info now

Comment: All think seems right! i think it's api error not your fault. check this and add library and check what response you gave from api when you call it from android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57473000/6401241

Comment: @Radesh I have updated my Post. But can't figure it out the actual problem

Comment: Never seen the syntax of `@field:SerializedName` before, try to replace it with `@SerializedName("name")` otherwise show the screen of the response structure in the debugger please.

Comment: @Daniel actually I used a plugin called RoboPojoGenerator to make pojo class from json response. the response in the image  https://imgur.com/a/FfuyDPH

Comment: I send Body in Parameter but in backend, Body object showed null. May be it was the problem. Can you guys have any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: with the fields you showed, if you receive an array like you showed, the gson deserializer should throw a deserialization error, if not then something is wrong.

Comment: @Daniel I have fixed the problem just now. But solution was weird. Use Field of name, email, password .. instead of Body